# Why does my app crash when I use an "if let" statement to unwrap an optional collectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am getting this error in xcode after months of this code working fine, and I can't for the life of me figure out why the code is throwing the error.

Error: *Thread 1: Fatal Error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

```
if let recentsRow = collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: recentsIndex) as? DashboardRowCollectionViewCell {
        recentsRow.documents = recents ?? []
}

if let favoritesRow = collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: favoritesIndex) as? DashboardRowCollectionViewCell {
        favoritesRow.documents = favorites ?? []
}
```

Sorry if this has already been asked, but I looked around the site for a while and still was unable to come up with a solution.

Edit: I do not have this issue when running the app in a simulator. I also didn't have this issue before I updated XCode.

Edit 2: The debugger has told me that collectionView is nil, but I am still unsure as to why it is nil.

Here is how collectionView is defined in my ViewController: `@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!`

Comment: Maybe it's the collection view that's nil? Or the index path?

Comment: Something is nil. Could you check the values in the debugger when it happens?

Comment: **Never ever** call the datasource method `collectionView(_ collectionView: cellForItemAt:)` yourself. Use always `cellForItem(at:` of `UICollectionView`.

Comment: @vadian How come I shouldn't use collectionView(_ collectionView: cellForItemAt:)?

Comment: Apparently it is the collectionView that's nil. But I am still confused why it is nil in the first place as this has never been an issue before and I haven't recently made changes to this ViewController. @Larme

Comment: It's one of the delegate / datasource methods which is called exclusively by the framework. And you will get a new dequeued cell which is not the cell you expect.

Comment: The `collectionView` itself might be `nil` if it's declared as `UICollectionView!`.

Comment: @Sulthan Why would it be nil? If it didn't have a problem registering cells in the viewDidLoad method how come it is nil later on?

Comment: @GraysonCroom Your code does not really specify *when* the code is executed.

Comment: @Sulthan Would it help if I posted the full view controller with the irrelevant parts redacted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not sure why the collectionview was nil in the first place, I fixed my application from crashing by surrounding the offending code with the following:

```
if collectionView != nil {
    ... code goes here ...
}
```

This will be the accepted answer until someone comes along to explain why it was nil to begin with.

Edit: If you are trying to figure out why it was nil and want the ViewController code that the problem belongs to, I'll be happy to provide it.